# Wordpress custom single-product.php: how is <a data-full=... changing the main image?

Tags: php, wordpress, srcset

I'm working on a WordPress site created by another developer, and the custom theme has broken in places due to WordPress updates. I've managed to fix most issues but this one has me stumped, mostly because I'm not sure exactly how it worked in the first place! I'm fairly new to PHP and WordPress, most of my experience being in HTML/CSS...
Anyways, I've already had to modify this code to fix a few issues, and it's current state [on the live site](http://mooreriveraccommodation.com/product/captains-cabin-guilderton-2/) is:

```
<div class="full rounded-corners" >
    <!-- first image is viewable to start -->
    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
</div>
<div class="previews">
<?php
global $wpdb;
$attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();

foreach ($attachment_ids as $attachment_id) {
    $sql = "SELECT guid FROM wp_1posts WHERE ID = " . $attachment_id;
    $row = $wpdb->get_row($sql);
    ?>
    <a data-full="<?php echo $row->guid; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $row->guid; ?>" width="56" height="58" /></a>

<?php } ?>
```

There is a main product image and some thumbnails, clicking on the thumbnails changes the main product image.

There are a couple of problems.

1. the new responsive images thing in WordPress using srcset breaks the function in which the main image changes when clicking the thumbs, it continues to show the main image.
   When inspecting the result I can see the img src is changing as expected, but the srcset is continuing to show the original.
   It works if responsive images is disabled.
2. This code pulls the largest version of the images which is causing loading problems.

I've tried to combat the second problem by changing the `<?php echo $row->guid;?>` to `<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'thumbnail');?>`.
This loads thumbs as expected, so I think this is a workable solution however this leaves me with the problem of the main image not changing (unless responsive images are disabled).

So on my local machine where I'm attempting to find a solution, it now looks like this:

```
<div class="full rounded-corners" >
    <!-- first image is viewable to start -->
    <?php echo the_post_thumbnail(); ?> 
</div>
<div class="previews">
    <?php
    global $product;
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
    foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
   ?>
       <a data-full="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>"> <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>" style="height:60px; width:auto;"></a>
   <?php }
   ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Thing is, I'm not sure **how** the original code causes the main image to change in the first place, so I'm not sure how to fix it. e.g. what is the `<a data-full=`... doing?? **Edit:** think i figured out data-full changes the main pic with the 'full' class is this right?

Can someone please explain to me how the original code is changing the main image when the thumbnails are clicked, and if possible, any hints as to how to fix the srcset issue?

When inspecting the main image after clicking a thumb:

```
<img style="display: inline;" src="http://localhost/MooreRiverWP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/View-to-Ocean.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="8 Harris Street" srcset="http://localhost/MooreRiverWP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/8-Harris-Street-200x133.jpeg 200w, http://localhost/MooreRiverWP/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/8-Harris-Street.jpeg 314w" sizes="(max-width: 314px) 100vw, 314px" height="209" width="314">
```

The src is correct, the srcset is not, and the image is displaying the srcset version.

**Edit:**
I now have the almost-working code on the live site, with responsive images disabled. I'd like to have the responsive images working but unless anyone can help, I think I'll have to admit defeat and leave it at that!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is javascript doing fancy things to make it work but here's a code snippet that would help you understand how to use the responsive images in WP 4.4 taken from [make.wordpress.org](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/11/10/responsive-images-in-wordpress-4-4/)

```
<?php
$img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $attachment_id, 'medium' );
$img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id, 'medium' );
?>
<img src="<?php echo esc_url( $img_src ); ?>"
     srcset="<?php echo esc_attr( $img_srcset ); ?>"
     sizes="(max-width: 50em) 87vw, 680px" alt="A rad wolf">
```

Note: you can change 'medium' to other wordpress default sizes such as 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'full'  or a custom size setup by yourself in functions.php

Note 2: the main thing that controls how the responsive works is the 'sizes' attribute which specifies what to display at what widths.  More information can be found here in [this tutorial](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-images-in-practice)

Comment: I did come across that exact code snippet while researching lol but couldn't make it work with this... There is no javascript that I can see unless it's getting pulled from elsewhere, don't know WordPress well enough to be sure that it doesn't sneak some in from somewhere though! There are no <script> tags at any rate. I'll have a read through that tutorial thanks :)

Comment: You may need to regenerate thumbnails so your new image is regenerated at the different resolutions.  You can try [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)